# Getting values from a collection with a complex JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to get the materials from a purchase order (Po) by its id. There are a few collections in the path and join tables.

Po.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "po", targetEntity = Po_part.class)
    private List<Po_part> partList;
```

Part.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_PART_MATERIAL",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="parts_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="materials_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Material> materials = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="part",targetEntity=Po_part.class)
    private List<Po_part> partList;
```

Po_part.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po_part implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Part part;

    @ManyToOne
    private Po po;
```

Material.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_MATERIAL")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Material implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Supplier supplier;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id_2", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Supplier supplier2;
```

JPA Query in the MaterialRespository

```
 @Query("SELECT m FROM Material m "
            + "JOIN Po po "
            + "JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "JOIN po_part.part parts "
            + "JOIN parts.materials materials "
            + "WHERE po.id = ?1")
     List<Material> getListOfMaterialsForPo(Long id);
```

The end result is I want to be able to get a list of materials required for a Po

-------UPDATE---------

I got the below Query to work on mySQL workbench but it only returns the inventory when I really need the actual Material object to access its getters. Not sure if this is solvable with SQL.

Query:

```
 @Query(value="SELECT materials.inventory_count materials "
                    +"FROM hillcresttooldie.t_po po "
                    +"join hillcresttooldie.t_po_part po_part "
                    +"on po_part.po_id = po.id "
                    +"join hillcresttooldie.t_part part "
                    +"on part.id = po_part.part_id "
                    +"join hillcresttooldie.T_PART_MATERIAL material "
                    +"on material.materials_id = part.id "
                    +"join hillcresttooldie.T_MATERIAL materials "
                    +"on material.materials_id = materials.id "
                    +"where po.id LIKE %?1", nativeQuery = true)
         List<Integer> getListOfMaterialsForPo(Long id);
```

Also another thing that really has me wondering is is there mySQL type work bench for JPA. In Eclipse I have the below add-on:

[image]

[image]

However I have never used it. Thought it would be helpful to add this to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time to actually learn JPQL. It's not that hard. JPQL uses associations to make joins. The query you need ias as simple as

```
select material from Po po
join po.partList popart
join popart.part part
join part.materials material
where po.id = :poId
```

And please, give meaninful names to your classes, and respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: What classes are you referring too? Thanks for the help, I am pretty new at JPA and correct it is not that hard but I am still getting the hang of it. I am self teaching myself. I did get it to work by creating a class, and using the NEW operator in JPA to initialize the class with the values I needed. However your solution is much simpler and I thank you.

Comment: Java class names NEVER contain underscores. Your are. Imagine yourself before starting this project, and helping me on StackOverflow, where I show you a class named `Po`. Would you have any idea what such a class represents? Now imagine Ishow you a class named PuchaseOrder? Isn't that much clearer now?